# Why does my React app result in a blank page when trying to serve from the build folder?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, build

I am having trouble serving a React App (I used Create-React-App specifically).

The website is currently at https://bsub.cl/blog/, and as one can observe, it currently yields a blank page. I tried inspecting what's going on and I see the following errors:

```
[Error] Did not parse stylesheet at 'https://bsub.cl/blog/static/css/main.6a87e0ff.chunk.css' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode.
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    (anonymous function) (2.f4f0bc71.chunk.js:1)
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    (anonymous function) (main.2a47de8b.chunk.js:1)
```

It seems that the error has to do with the static files (.js and .css), but I don't know how to solve it.

What I tried was simply clone my repo in the server, run `yarn run build`, edit the nginx config and expect it to work.

As it might be relevant, my nginx configuration is

```
server {
 server_name bsub.cl;
 ...
 location /blog/ {
    root /<path to build>/build;
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
 }
 ...
}
```

Also in case it is relevant, I have the following line in the `package.json` file.

```
"homepage": "https://bsub.cl/blog/",
```

Any hints on what exactly could be going on? Is there a better way to serve my react app?

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` because the response is HTML, not JavaScript. Your push-state routing fallback is responding with `index.html` for too many things.

Comment: But shouldn't the `try_files $uri ...` make it look for the static files when a `.jss` or `.css` is requested?